# Can I adjust the rendered view background?

Tags: interface, customization

The new rendered view background bothers me a lot. The big checkered background literally hurts my eyes to look at it. Is there a way to adjust it on 2.83 or do I have to change it back to 2.81?

Please don't judge the artwork. It's an earlier version I happened to screenshot for critique

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the checker size and colors in:
*Preferences > Themes > User Interface > Transparent Checkerboard*

To get rid of the checkerboard entirely, set both colors to be the same.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Jachym!